# The isomorphisms between two vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, abstract-algebra

Let $V$ and $W$ be two vector spaces over real number field, if they are isomorphic as vector spaces over rational number field, are they isomorphic as real  vector spaces ?

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Of course you know that $\Bbb R$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ as $\Bbb R$ vector spaces.

Did you check to see what the $\Bbb Q$ dimensions of both of those spaces would be?

Answer (score 5):

No. $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are isomorphic as vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$ but not as vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What isomorphism could you use for $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Dear @FireGarden : I think the easiest thing to do is to just note $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^2$ have the same $\Bbb Q$ dimension, so they are isomorphic. I doubt an explicit isomorphism is possible, since it's already difficult to describe these bases. Or else you could just say "find a $\Bbb Q$ basis for $\Bbb R$, and then use that same basis to construct a new basis for $\Bbb R^2$, using interleaving to make an isomorphism.

Comment: If $V$ is a vector space over a countable field like $\mathbb{Q}$ and $B$ is a basis for $V$, then $V$ and $B$ have the same cardinality. Hence as $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ have the same cardinality, they have bases with the same cardinality and hence are isomorphic as vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$. This argument relies on the existence of bases, and the proof that any vector space has a basis requires the axiom of choice. So the argument doesn't give a specific description of the isomorphism.

Comment: The first sentence in my previous comment should begin "If $V$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space over a countable field".